# why some custom OS devices can not detection sms in android?

Tags: kotlin

I am using SmsRetrieverClient & AppSignatureHelper to detect SMS and now I am facing issues about can not detect OTP with some custom OS devices like OPPO, OnePlus, etc. and I can not clarify the reason. Pls, help me!

I have tried with SmsRetrieverClient & AppSignatureHelper and broasdcast and the result is some devices working and some not.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears Google's update has created some issues on Android 13 either due to play service version or something else on custom OS devices. Check this  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/275036593

Hope they fix it asap